# Should I overwrite boilerplates' package.json and git history?

Tags: git, package.json, boilerplate

Boilerplates like [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate) or [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) are great to bootstrap new projects, but the "name", "author" and "repository" fields in `package.json` are no longer representative when they become private/internal projects.

Should I just overwrite those and put new, more relevant values?

The same applies for the git history of cloned projects: is it best to just delete the `.git` folder and `git init` for personnal use?

Comment: Quite simply, yes. ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks @evolutionxbox! I find that those projects often encourage users to edit the "useful" parts, but never mention explicitely what to do with meta files (`package.json`, `CHANGELOG`, `CODE_OF_CONDUCT`, ...)

Comment: `package.json` https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json/ and https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json --- `CODE_OF_CONDUCT` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_conduct --- `CHANGELOG` https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/

Comment: I think htis is primarily opinion based/too broad.

Comment: I just wanted to know what's best practice (if there is one).